# Same url for multiple sharepoint web apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to have a single url to access multiple sharepoint web apps? For example in our installation we have 3 web apps

1. mysites.hostnamme
2. teamsites.hostname
3. portal.hostname

Is it possible to have a single url like

1. www.mydomain.com/mysites
2. www.mydomain.com/teamsites
3. www.mydomain.com/portal

to redirect to those corresponding web apps? Or do I have to make it all in a single web app if so is that recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need different authentication, separate search indices, etc. for your web applications, you'll probably be better off with a single web app and multiple site collections for your portal, team and my sites.